# Searching Details on basis of Name and start date to end date

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image]

I have created a web page which filters data according to the name and from date to end date and display data into the gridview and I have single date column(using between I have to filter data)

I've tried subquery and aslo used stored procedure for the same. I want the data to be displayed on the basis of search button in c#.

Here's The Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_PartySearch]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @vendorname varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    SELECT * from [dbo].[vw_PODetails] where VendorName like '%'+@VendorName+'%'
    order by PODate desc
END
```

--Code Behind for Button

```
 protected void part_ser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_PartySearch", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendorname",partyser.Text);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
            GridView1.Visible = true;

        }
```

which query i can use for filtering date in procedure

Comment: In SQL u can use `like ` keyword for name search and `between` for date

Comment: Can you post the code which you tried and did not work? Also, do you have separate filters for `dates` and the `Name` and when user select it is going to work accordingly depending upon the filters selected?

Comment: first thing, by using single date column how you can search for 2 dates( i.e. start and end dates)?
second, your question can't say any problem to viewers. Please elaborate your question and show your code too.

Comment: I have to filter the data from date column based on Invoice date to check the report for sales between these dates

Comment: Please include the database's table DDL and the C# code to retrieve the values from the user input.